# Google NaCl get IP and system information

Tags: ip-address, glibc, function-calls, google-nativeclient

Beginner question

Problem
Function calls *gethostbyname, getifaddrs, uname, system* always fails.

I guess that the Native Client runtime system prevents executing considering it as
unsafe activity?

If that's true, what is an alternative?

On getifaddrs and uname I get error:  ENOSYS Function not implemented

On gethostbyname I get error: Unknown Server Error

I'm using glibc

Answer (score 0):

If you can reliably get it on the JavaScript side you could send it over as a message.

Comment: Unfortunately, the task is to obtain this information in c++ module and send it as a message to the JavaScript side.